# How to use client authentication certificate with boost?

Tags: c++, boost-beast, beast

I am trying to figure out how to tell Boost Beast to use a client authentication certificate during the SSL handshake.

I have looked at the Boost Beast documentation, but have been unable to find any hint on client side certificates. The examples also do not cover this case.

Comment: All the (HTTPS) [examples](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/beast/doc/html/beast/examples.html) in the documentation use certificates. See 'Common Files' at the bottom.

Comment: Boost.Beast doesn't handle any SSL or TLS related things, for that you need to look to Boost.Asio's `ssl::stream` class template: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ssl__stream.html

Comment: @VinnieFalco least helpful comment possible.